# JQuery dialog destroy

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui-dialog

How can I implement in jQuery to call in the dialog "Ok" function the destroy method?

```
$('.dialog').dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  width: 600,
  buttons: {
    "Ok": function() { 
      $(this).dialog("close");
    }, 
    "Cancel": function() { 
      $(this).dialog("close"); 
    } 
  }
});

$('.dialog_link').click(function(){
  $('.dialog').dialog('open');
  return false;
});
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thank you, how can I include the `link_to` function in the ajax request?

Comment: Is nobody able to help me? Or is the problem unclear? I need really your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the solution

**HTML:**

```
<a href="users/***Item id***"
```

**JQuery:**

```
$('.dialog_link').click(function(){
  url = this;

  $('.dialog').dialog('open');
  return false;
});

$('.dialog').dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  width: 600,
  buttons: {
    "Ok": function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'post',
        data: { '_method': 'delete' },
        success: function(html){
          $("body").html(html)
        }
    })
    $(this).dialog("close"); 
    }, 
    "Cancel": function() { 
    $(this).dialog("close"); 
    } 
  }
});
```

Kind regards shub

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use an AJAX request.

Read the documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/